# Odd ListView row behavior when using layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm using a ListView where each row has 3 TextViews. Pretty simple, right?

I would like to use weights rather than fixing the widths but that seems to really screw things up for some reason.

This is the Layout for my rows:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
android:weightSum="7">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listCaseName"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:width="0dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listCaseStatus"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:width="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listPDF"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:width="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything looks fine until I scroll down, select an item and scroll back up. (I have some special code for highlighting the selected row, but I'm pretty sure that's not the problem)

Here's what the listview looks like initially (perfectly fine):
[image: listviewWeightsInitial]

this is what it looks like when I scroll back up after clicking on an item:

[image: scrollingBackUp]

there's a bunch of extra space (the big gray block)

and when I scroll up further it looks like this:

[image: scrollingUpFurther]

some of the text gets messed up too.

I can alleviate the problem by fixing the widths of the textviews instead of using weights.

I'm clueless.  I have a bit of experience with listviews, but until now I have always used fixed sizes for things, and never had any trouble.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting `android:width` and `android:layout_width` to 0 instead of just `android:layout_width`?

Comment: So now I have layout_width set to 0 and i got rid of width... It seems to be okay so far... I thought you always had to set width to 0 when using weights... I tried width="0dp" with layout_width="fill_parent"/"wrap_content"/"0dp" and none of those had an effect. Android layouts still mystify me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call `myView.invalidate()` on the click?

Comment: any solution on this thread ? just experience the same thing, calling listview.invalidate() makes it worse. any idea ?

Comment: the OP doesn't seem very active